# Ordered list in Gmail with letters instead of numbers?

Tags: gmail, text-formatting

The Gmail composer appears to only offer numbered and bulleted lists.  Shortcuts:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> for a numbered list
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> for a bulleted list

Is there a straightforward way to create an ordered list that uses letters instead of numbers?  I.e.,

```
A. First item
B. Second item
```

instead of

```
1. First item
2. Second item
```

Answer (score 5):

When I want specific formatting (such as tables), I write the email in Word first then paste it in Gmail. I tried it with your example of lettered bullets and it worked well. I haven't found another option directly in Gmail unless there is an extension that gives more formatting options.

Answer (score 5):

With one caveat, there is a simple way to do this using the `Developer Tools` of your web browser.

**Caveat: There does not seem to be a "straightforward" way to do this** directly through the unmodified Gmail formatting bar available today in the web-browser version of the Gmail App.  This feature simple has not yet been developed by Google into the Gmail web application.

However, not all hope is lost!

There is a *somewhat* straightforward workaround worth considering if the order-list formatting is essential enough to warrant some minor effort.

### 1. Make a formatted `ordered list` in Gmail

First, in Gmail – if you haven't already done so – you need to make an ordered list.

1. Click the `formatting tools` button on the toolbar on the bottom of the email it looks like a small, underlined, and capitalized letter `A̲`.
2. Then select your lines you would like to create the ordered list from and click the ordered list button it looks like this [image: Google's ordered list icon]

### 2. Use `Developer Tools`

1. Right-click your list and choose `Inspect` or whatever equivalent option the browser you're using has.  This will bring up that HTML element in your browser's developer tools.
2. Find the `<ol>` tag.  You might have "Inspected" an inner `<li>` tag, in which case, just look to the parent tag that wraps the list you'd like to change the order style on.
3. Right-click the `<ol>` tag and choose `Add Attribute`.
4. By simply typing `type='A'` and then hitting the `enter` key, you will set the `type` attribute of the `<ol>` tag of your list equal to `'A'`.

#### 3. *Voilà!*

Now, look at the edited list in Gmail.  You should instantly see the change reflected in the body of the email you're writing.

### More options on the `Ordered List` element's `type` attribute

> `type` – sets the numbering type:
>
> - `a` for lowercase letters
> - `A` for uppercase letters
> - `i` for lowercase Roman numerals
> - `I` for uppercase Roman numerals
> - `1` for numbers (default)
>
> See [Mozilla's MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol#attr-type) for more styling options for the `Ordered List` element.

### Trouble opening your browser's `Developer Tools`?

Common browser's `Devloper Tool`'s `Inspect` option:

- [Chrome's `Inspect` Tool](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/open/#inspect)
- [Firefox's `Inspect` Tool](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/page_inspector/how_to/open_the_inspector/index.html)
- Safari's `Inspect` Tool

  Well, Apple's documentation on this feature is lacking.  So, here:

  1. Enable `Show Develop menu in menu bar` in Safari's settings under the `Advanced` tab.  [Detailed instructions here](https://support.apple.com/guide/safari/use-the-developer-tools-in-the-develop-menu-sfri20948/mac).
  2. Now you can right-click or use the Context Menu and chose `Inspect Element`

---

### Deeper understanding, credit, and related links

When using Gmail's built-in formatting tool, Gmail will format your email in [HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML) under the hood when using Gmail's built-in formatting tool.  This means that you have several options to work around this issue.

- You can use your browser's developer tools.  When you make a change to the HTML elements in the developer tools those changes will directly edit the content of the email you're writing in the Gmail web application.  [More on `Developer Tools` in various browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools)
- You may be able to copy/paste already HTML formatted content from another authoring application to achieve a similar effect.  However, keep in mind that everyone's copy/paste formatting experience will vary greatly based on a number of factors.  The discussion of which is outside of the scope of this answer.

If you're sending the email in `plane-text mode` that is, not HTML, then you can simply ignore all of these fancy formatting instructions and type the raw text in, without any special formatting.

#### Documentation:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol#attr-type
- https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists_ordered.asp

#### Credit:

- Original site that lead me to this expanded answer: https://www.plausiblenonsense.com/2015/12/starting-numbered-list-at-different.html
- Tool I used to get an underlined `A̲` on Stackoverflow that looks like Google's Formatting button: https://manytools.org/facebook-twitter/strikethrough-text/
- Google's Ordered List icon: https://fonts.google.com/icons?icon.query=List&icon.set=Material+Icons