# Ordered list in Superhuman with letters instead of numbers?

Tags: untagged

Same question as [Ordered list in Gmail with letters instead of numbers?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/142136/ordered-list-in-gmail-with-letters-instead-of-numbers) but for [Superhuman](https://superhuman.com/) instead of Gmail.

The Superhuman composer appears to only offer numbered and bulleted lists.  Shortcuts:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> for a numbered list
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> for a bulleted list

Is there a straightforward way to create an ordered list that uses letters instead of numbers?

```
A. First item
B. Second item
```

Instead of:

```
1. First item
2. Second item
```

Comment: Do you know if superhuman has a help center or end-users resources? If so please search it, add what you found and why it didn't meet your needs.